# IBM Mobile First platform v7.1 custom security test is not found in authenticationConfig.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I have been trying to follow the tutorials on this website:
[Tutorials](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/form-based-authentication/form-based-authentication-hybrid-applications/)

I have run into trouble trying to set up a simple form based authentication to an adapter procedure.
When I try to push my adapter:

```
MacBook-Pro-Savid:AuthAdapter bruser$ mfp push
Preparing for push...
Verifying Server Configuration...
Runtime 'HelloWorldPrject' will be used to push the project into.
Pushing to Server...
Deploying 
/Users/bruser/javad_test_folder/HelloWorldPrject/bin/AuthAdapter.adapter... 
Error: Failed to deploy 
/Users/bruser/javad_test_folder/HelloWorldPrject/bin/AuthAdapter.adapter. 
Reason: failed to push adapter: Required security test 'AuthSecurity' for 
resource proc:AuthAdapter.getSecretData' wasn't found in 
authenticationConfig.xml: HTTP 200 - OK.
adapter found here: 
/Users/bruser/javad_test_folder/HelloWorldPrject/bin/AuthAdapter.adapter has 
been build but deployment failed.
Error: Push has failed here
```

My */server/conf/authenticationConfig.xml*:

```
    <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
         5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
         US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
         disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. -->

 <staticResources>
 <!--
        <resource id="logUploadServlet" securityTest="LogUploadServlet">
        <urlPatterns>/apps/services/loguploader*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>
    -->
    <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
        <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>

</staticResources>

 <securityTests>

     <customSecurityTest name="AuthSecurity">
         <test realm="SampleAppRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/>
     </customSecurityTest>
    <!--
    <mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests">
        <testAppAuthenticity/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
        <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" />
        <testDirectUpdate mode="perSession" />
    </mobileSecurityTest>

    <webSecurityTest name="webTests">
        <testUser realm="myWebLoginForm"/>
    </webSecurityTest>

    <customSecurityTest name="customTests">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
    </customSecurityTest>

    <customSecurityTest name="LogUploadServlet">
        <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="LogUploadServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
    -->
</securityTests>

<realms>
    <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>

    <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>

    <!-- For client logger -->
    <!-- <realm name="LogUploadServlet" loginModule="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
    </realm -->

    <!-- For websphere -->
    <!-- realm name="WASLTPARealm" loginModule="WASLTPAModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/>
        <parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html"/>
    </realm -->

    <!-- For User Certificate Authentication -->
    <!-- realm name="wl_userCertificateAuthRealm" loginModule="WLUserCertificateLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="dependent-user-auth-realm" value="WASLTPARealm" />
        <parameter name="pki-bridge-class" value="com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateEmbeddedPKI" />
        <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-file-path" value="/opt/ssl_ca/ca.p12"/>
        <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-password" value="capassword" />
    </realm -->

    <!-- For Trusteer Fraud Detection -->
    <!-- Requires acquiring Trusteer SDK -->
    <!-- realm name="wl_basicTrusteerFraudDetectionRealm" loginModule="trusteerFraudDetectionLogin">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.TrusteerAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="rooted-device" value="block"/>
        <parameter name="device-with-malware" value="block"/>
        <parameter name="rooted-hiders" value="block"/>
        <parameter name="unsecured-wifi" value="alert"/>
        <parameter name="outdated-configuration" value="alert"/>
    </realm -->

    <!-- For enabling custom authentication -->
    <!-- The className shouldn't be changed, it is part of the framework  -->
    <!--  <realm name="customAuthRealm" loginModule="customAuthLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.CustomIdentityAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="providerUrl" value="http://localhost:3000"/>
    </realm> -->

</realms>

<loginModules>
    <loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="requireLogin" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="rejectAll" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <!-- Required for Trusteer - wl_basicTrusteerFraudDetectionRealm -->
    <!-- loginModule name="trusteerFraudDetectionLogin" expirationInSeconds="300">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.TrusteerLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule-->

    <!-- For websphere -->
    <!-- loginModule name="WASLTPAModule" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule -->

    <!-- Login module for User Certificate Authentication -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="WLUserCertificateLoginModule" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->


    <!-- For enabling SSO with no-provisioning device authentication -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->


    <!-- For enabling SSO with auto-provisioning device authentication -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceAutoProvisioningLoginModule" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->

    <!-- For enabling custom authentication -->
    <!-- The className shouldn't be changed, it is part of the framework  -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="customAuthLoginModule" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.CustomIdentityLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->
</loginModules>

<!--staticResources>
    <resource id="mobileFirstConsole" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
        <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>
</staticResources-->
```

Comment: protect your authAdapter with "webTests" instead of "AuthSecurity" and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this error

Reason: failed to push adapter: Required security test 'AuthSecurity' for 
resource proc:AuthAdapter.getSecretData' wasn't found in 
authenticationConfig.xml:

It is looking for the 'AuthSecurity' Test which is not found in the authenticationConfig.xml which is part of the runtime WAR that is deployed on the server.

procedure name="getSecretData" securityTest="AuthSecurityTest"

this means you need to extract the WAR from the server and double check if it in fact exists in the authenticationConfig.xml which looks like it is not there based on the exception

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/form-based-authentication/